# Disable JIRA e-mail notifications to one user

Tags: jira, wiki, jira-agile

One of our JIRA users wants to disable the option to receive any kind of e-mail from JIRA and updates from the wiki.

How can this be implemented? Please provide the exact steps so that it can be switched off, or explain what I can do to create that something.

JIRA v7.1.4

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in Jira.

You can edit the email record to point somewhere else.

If it's user from external user directory (for example ActiveDirectory) you can delete email attribute in that user directory.

The cleanest way will be filtering out all incoming email from your jira server on user's mailbox side.